# Get the number of organic search users and sessions for a channel group in GA4 in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I would like to get the number of users or sessions for the channel group "Organic Search". I would like to get it separately for each URL.

```
WITH
prep as (
    SELECT
        (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS page_location,
        CASE
            WHEN
                regexp_contains(traffic_source.source, r'^(google|bing|yahoo|baidu|duckduckgo|yandex|ask)$')
                OR traffic_source.medium = 'organic'
            THEN 'Organic Search'
        ELSE
            'others'
        END AS default_channel_group
    FROM
        `bigquery-ga4-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
    WHERE
        _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230801' AND '20230831'
)

SELECT
    page_location,
    SUM(CASE WHEN default_channel_group = 'Organic Search' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS organic_search
FROM
    prep
GROUP BY
    page_location
```

With a query like the one above, you can probably get a value close to the number of events, but if you want this to be the number of users or sessions instead of the number of events, how do you construct the query?

It would be helpful if you could give me an example query.